# How can I filter distinct values on a dropdown menu coming from an excel sheet on PowerApps?

Tags: sorting, filter, distinct, dropdown, powerapps

I have a dropdown menu, which accesses an Excel sheet called `Clothes` and takes in the distinct values from the column `Color` and then sorts them in ascending order with the following statement:

```
Sort(Distinct(Clothes,Color),Result,Ascending)
```

My `Color` column contains the following values:

```
Green
Blue
Grey
Red
Yellow
Pink
```

What I wanna do is filter the colors that contain the color letter g inside them in the dropdown. I would like for instance to only see `Green` and `Grey` after applying the filter. I tried the following:

```
Sort(Distinct(Filter(Clothes, "g" in Lower(Color))),Result,Ascending)
```

But I get an error saying:

```
The function 'Sort' has some invalid arguments. Invalid number of arguments 
received 1, expected: 2
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like your distinct function is lacking a required argument! According to the Distinct reference docs found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct), the Distinct function takes a Table argument, and a Formula argument. Your Table argument is the result of the Filter being applied, the Formula may be something like the column name you are trying to get distinct values from. In your case, most likely 'Clothes'.

```
Sort(Distinct(Filter(Clothes, "g" in Lower(Color)), <Formula goes here>),Result, Ascending)
```

Here is the example on how Distinct works from the documentation mentioned above.

**Example**

If you had an Employees table that contained a Department column, this function would list each unique department name in that column, no matter how many times each name appeared in that column:

Distinct(Employees, Department)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, this helped me solve my problem and understand better how the functions work

Comment: Glad I could help mate!